# asp.net mvc submit doesnt hit actionresult method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

would you mind to help me and say what I am doing wrong? I cannot spot the error and consequently after clicking the submit button, the HttpPost ActionResult method is not being hit?

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(testModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid == true)
    {
        using (testRepository repository = new testRepository())
        {

        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

And the View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new {autocomplete="off" }))
{
    <fieldset>     
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.testValue)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.testValue)
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: does the browser make a post request?
where does it go?
what's rendered as action for the form?

Comment: 1) Have you changed the routing from the default? 2) Is the controller that the `Index` methods are in named `TestController`? 3) Does the controller subclass `Controller` (not `ApiController`)?

Comment: It looks like it was not working only for Firefox which is very weird. I did forget to check it across the other browsers. Thanks.

Comment: Routing is fine. It was the very first thing I have checked.

Comment: I does not change anything. I did check it as well.

Comment: Try add "antiforgerytoken" in the form and in the controller

Comment: Do you have nested forms?

Comment: I do not have nested forms and antiforgerytoken does not solve the issue for Firefox. It works fine for Chrome and other browsers though.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].